# Warning when deploying JBPM 5.3 to JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, jbpm

When I deploy my app with JBPM to JBoss I get following warning:

```
 07:43:30,597 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
```

This class comes from the transitive dependency smack-3.0.4 of jbpm-human-task.

The question is should I worry (I don't see any problems at the moment) how can I avoid this warning?
And what does this warning mean?

Kind regards

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't worry, the warning will not impact performance of jboss or
   your application unless you're using the jBPM jabber work item.
2. The warning has to do with dependencies in the jbpm-workitems jar that's apparently packaged with your app. If you're not using jbpm-workitems, removing that jar might fix the error. (or see 3.)
3. [This comment](https://community.jboss.org/message/744927#744927) on the jboss community forums explains that a config file in the smack jar is incorrectly formatted. You could change that config file in the smack jar to make it go away.